# In SQL Server, what is "Partitioned Table Parallelism" that is only available in Enterprise Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, partitioning, parallelism, enterprise-edition

I am reviewing the [differences between Standard and Enterprise editions of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSSP) and can't reproduce the differences advertised in this [demo that explains the differences](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Joe+Longtin/Demo-SQL-Server-2008-Partitioned-Table-Parallelism) - the performance I observe when running a query across Standard and Enterprise are comparable, and queries run in parallel across partitioned tables in the execution plan.

I have verified that:

- The queries produce identical query plans
- The queries produce similar runtime with `set statistics time on`

It seems that in SQL Server 2016 this difference is not reproducible. Is there something else this feature affects - maybe I am not testing for the right thing but the queries are comparable to that in the demo.

This is the script I have used to test:

```
-- MAXDOP is 10

--  structure of table
--Column                type
--testData.PKcolumn1    bigint
--testData.PKcolumn2    int
--date                  datetime
--testData.PKcolumn3    bigint
--metric1               float
--metric2               float
--metric3               float
--metric4               float

--index_description                                                 index_keys
--clustered, unique, primary key located on ps_testData             categoryId, transactionId, date

--pf_testData/ps_testData is a range right datetime partition scheme,  fanout 368
GO

-- Actual partition count: 368
-- all 10 threads participate in the scan, 12MM to 13MM rows / thread 
--      each partition likely read by a single thread
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(date), MAX(date)
FROM testData
GO

-- Actual partitions with data count: 31
-- all 10 threads participate in the scan, 3MM to 4MM rows / thread 
--      each partition likely read by a single thread
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(date), MAX(date)
FROM testData
WHERE date >= '2020-01-01' AND date < '2020-02-01'
GO

-- Actual partitions with data count: 7
-- all 10 threads participate in the scan, with a range of 0.5MM to 1MM rows per thread 
-- some partitions were read by multiple threads
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(date), MAX(date)
FROM testData
WHERE date >= '2020-01-01' AND date < '2020-01-08'
GO

-- Actual partitions with data count: 1
-- all 10 threads participate in the scan, 60K to 100K rows / thread (all threads read from a single partition)
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(date), MAX(date)
FROM testData
WHERE date >= '2020-01-01' AND date < '2020-01-02'
GO
```

- [SQL Standard Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk58a2yrP)
- [SQL Enterprise Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1BclT1HD)

n.b. This query has a group by clause - both show parallelism across partitions and within the same partition.

Answer (score 2):

### TMWFR

This was a documentation error. I blogged about the results of many tests comparing parallel queries against partitioned tables here:

- [Partitioning And Parallelism](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/partitioning-and-parallelism/)

That resulted in the documentation getting updated to reflect that there is *no difference*

- [RDBMS scalability and performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#RDBMSSP)

[image: NUTS]